# Is it possible to suppress parent's :active pseudo class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="parent">
  I should change my color to green when clicked
  <div class="element">I should do nothing when clicked</div>
</div>
```

Here is the related CSS:

```
.parent {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
.parent:active {
  background:green;
}
.element {
  background:blue;
}
```

Is there any way to prevent triggering `.parent`'s `:active` pseudo class when `.element` is clicked? Tried `e.stopPropogation()` when `.element` is clicked with no luck.
[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cKgHD)

Comment: I guess that the jQuery `.stopPropogation()` has no effect on css rendering, just on JavaScript events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use jQuery instead of `:active`, like in this [demo (link)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEBfC).

```
$('.element').mousedown(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.parent').mousedown(function(e){
  $('.parent').css('background', 'green')
    }).mouseup(function(e){
  $('.parent').css('background', 'red')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close to the way, I do now, till I hav no better solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about on the parent introduce an extra class eg `allow-active`

```
<div class="parent allow-active">
```

Then amend your css so `.parent:active` becomes

```
.parent.allow-active:active {
    background:green;
}
```

Meaning the colour only changes if the div has both `parent` and `allow-active` classes

Then a bit of jQuery to toggle the `allow-active` class

```
$('.element').mousedown(function(e){
    $('.parent').removeClass('allow-active');
}).mouseup(function(e){
    $('.parent').addClass('allow-active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

possible with js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){
$(this).css("background","green")
    });
   $(".parent .element").click(function(e) {
       return false;
   });
});
```

and the css

```
.parent {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;

}
.parent:active {

}
.element {
  background:blue;

}
```

HTML is same

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to Doorknob's would be using the `event.target`:

```
$('.parent').mousedown(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is(this))
        $('.parent').css('background', 'green');
}).mouseup(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is(this))
        $('.parent').css('background', 'red');
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJALb).